# How to use useParams inside a useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to use `useParams` inside of `useEffect` but I am getting error saying that "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')".

app.js

```
<Route>
  <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductDetails />} />
</Route>
```

ProductDetails.js

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProductDetails(match.params.id));
  }, [dispatch, match.params.id]);`
```

It is giving me error as I have mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you half converted some code/logic from `react-router@5` where there was a `match` prop injected into the component to `react-router@6` where you instead use the `useParams` hook. `match` is simply undefined so an error is thrown when attempting to access into it a `params` property.

The `useParams` hook ***replaces entirely*** `props.match.params`. The `id` route path parameter alone is the dependency now.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const { id } = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getProductDetails(id));
}, [dispatch, id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to use a hook *inside* of a useEffect function. To answer your question

You could try this

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProductDetails(match?.params?.id));
  }, [dispatch, match?.params?.id]);`
```

But you're using javascript not typescript, so you can try this.

```
const param = match && match.params ? match.params.id : ''

useEffect(() => {
  if (param) {
    dispatch(getProductDetails(param));
  }
}, [dispatch, param]);
```

Comment: "I don't think you want to use a hook inside of a useEffect function" more than that, you **can't**, it violates the rules of hooks.

Comment: Thats what i mean to imply.... thanks though.